# How do I use an array of object parameters to set the value of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of parameters that are shared between two objects.

```
attributes = [:name, :category, :value]
```

The first object already has those parameters set. I would like to pass those same values onto the second object.

How do I do this?

My initial thought was to use:

```
attributes.each do |attribute|
    @object_2.(attribute) = object_1.(attribute)
end
```

I also tried putting the attribute variable inside of "#{attribute}" but it still did not work.

I've tried a number of different solutions with no help, and Googling the answer for the past hour has not helped.

Some of the results seemed to suggest that I could accomplish what I was looking for with the send() method, but my attempts to use it did not help.

```
attributes.each do |attribute|
    @object_2.send(attribute) = object_1.send(attribute)
end
```

If this question has been answered before (I could not find a solution by extensive searching) please point me towards a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
attributes.each do |attribute|
    @object_2.send("#{attribute}=", object_1.send(attribute))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a Hint about how this can also be done:

```
class Fred
  def initialize(p1 = nil, p2 = nil)
    @a, @b = p1, p2
  end
  def show
   p [@a,@b]
  end
end

f1 = Fred.new(10,11)
f2 = Fred.new
f1.instance_variables.each do |v|
  f2.instance_variable_set(v,f1.instance_variable_get(v))
end
f2.show #=>[10, 11
```

You can also replace `f1.instance_variables` by `attributes`, if you want assignments to only some selected instance variables,not all.

Answer (score 1):

```
@object_2.attributes = object_1.attributes
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably close in your last attempt, assuming you have declared `attr_accessor` for all the attributes in the respective class(es):

```
attributes.each do |attribute|
    setter = (attribute.to_s + '=').to_sym
    @object_2.send( setter, object_1.send( attribute ) )
end
```

The `.to_sym` is optional, I just like to work with symbols when working with introspection.

There are also ways to do this without needing the instance variables exposed via `attr_accessor` (it's not clear whether you need that)